# What does InsertRow() return if the insert is not successful?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1

I have some basic code that inserts rows using an `InsertCursor`.

```
oc = arcpy.da.InsertCursor(outputFC, someFields)

for item in rowsForInsertCursor:
    tmp = oc.insertRow(item)

del oc
```

It seems the return value from `InsertRow()` is a `long` containing the `ObjectId` of the row inserted. What is returned if something goes wrong and the row IS NOT inserted? I haven't been able to create a failure scenario but should consider it can happen.

Comment: Normally -1 is returned as a fail value where 0 - MaxInt are valid values, anything less than 0 could be considered a fail. I can't substantiate this with any documentation but it has many precedents. Consider declaring your cursor as *with arcpy.da.InsertCursor(outputFC, someFields) as oc:* which will clean it up when it's finished - this only works for arcpy.da cursors.

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson use `with arcpy.da.InsertCursor(outputFC, someFields) as oc` and I can remove the `del oc`?

Comment: Yup, that's it. The with statement is a python thing that can also be used on files etc.. it starts a new block and automatically calls del at the end... note: new indentation level using with. Check out the examples at http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018w00000011000000

Comment: I assume you could create a failure by just trying insertRow("fail") or adding an extra piece to the list: insertRow(item + [1])

Answer (score 4):

Insert Cursor can trip up on several things:

- sequence size not matching row size
- incorrect type
- trying to update fields that are not in the table/feature class
- trying to update fields not defined in the cursor fields

see examples below.[image]